# kubernetes cluster migration

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I currently have multiple AWS accounts each with it's own Kubernetes cluster. Unfortunately, when the clusters were initially deployed using kops VPCs were created with overlapping CIDR blocks. This normally wouldn't be a problem as each cluster essentially existed in it's own universe.

Things have changed a bit and now we want to implement cross account VPC peering. The idea is users connect over the VPN have have access to all resources through said peering. My understanding is the CIDR block overlap is going to be a major problem when peering is implemented.

It doesn't seem one can just change the CIDR block of the existing cluster.  Is my only option to backup and restore the cluster in a new VPC with something like ark? Has anyone gone through a full cluster migration? I'd be curious if there is a better answer.

Comment: Hi there, can you please provide details on your cluster & deployment tooling? How many workloads (Deployments and the like) are running in your cluster? How many nodes? What kind of in-cluster persistence are you using? Number of EBS volumes? Are you using a CSI tool (e.g. Portworx)? What do you use to deploy (e.g. Helm, static YAML files)? Answers to these questions would shed light on what it would take to migrate your cluster because yes, you can't change CIDR blocks of an existing cluster; it's stuck in the VPC in which it was created, and you can't change CIDR blocks in VPCs.

Comment: Cluster deployed via kops. over 50 nodes. Over 600 deployments. Persistence includes some PVCs (less than 5). Lots of EBS volumes. No Portworx. Helm is used. That's the small cluster

Comment: Ok, I'm not too familiar with Ark, but after a cursory look it seems to do what you need it to do. I have quite a bit of experience migrating clusters, however the "Lots of EBS volumes" part is something I have intentionally avoided for the very reason of cluster migrations and DR. My team and I have made it a rule to keep persistence out of the cluster, for now at least. I'll research this though b/c I have an early flight and won't sleep; let's see if someone beats me to an answer though :)

Comment: ignore the lots of ebs volumes part. that was a bit of a mistype on my part. really only prometheus alert manager has persistent volumes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: with kops, you can't change CIDR blocks of an existing cluster; it's stuck in the VPC in which it was created, and [you can't change the CIDR block of a VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-ip-address-range/):

> The IP address range of a VPC is made up of the CIDR blocks associated
>   with it. You select one CIDR block when you create the VPC, and you
>   can add or remove secondary CIDR blocks later. **The CIDR block that you
>   add when you create the VPC cannot be changed**, but you can add and
>   remove secondary CIDR blocks to change the IP address range of the
>   VPC. (emphasis mine)

That leads us to the second point: migrating your cluster. This can be broken down into two phases:

1. Migrating the infrastructure managed by `kops`
2. Migrating the workloads on the cluster

**1. Migrating the infrastructure managed by `kops`**

You will need to migrate (i.e. recreate) the kops cluster itself: the ec2 instances, kops `InstanceGroups` and `Cluster` objects, various AWS infrastructure, etc. For that, you can use the `kops toolbox template` command:

```
kops toolbox template --values /path/to/values.yaml --template /path/to/cluster/template.yaml > /path/to/output/cluster.yaml
kops create -f /path/to/output/cluster.yaml
```

This is a Helm-like tool that allows you to templatize your kops cluster configuration and pass in different `values.yaml` files. You might want to include this command within a small shell script wrapper or a Makefile to create 1-click cluster deployments to get your k8s cluster infrastructure set up easily and repeatably.

A sample cluster template.yaml file and values.yaml file might look like the following, which includes the specs for the `Cluster`, and master, worker, and autoscale `InstanceGroup`s.

```
# template.yaml
{{ $clusterSubdomain := (env "CLUSTER_SUBDOMAIN") }}
{{ $subnetCidr := (env "SUBNET_CIDR") }}

apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: {{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
spec:
  hooks:
  - manifest: |
      [Unit]
      Description=Create example user
      ConditionPathExists=!/home/example/.ssh/authorized_keys

      [Service]
      Type=oneshot
      ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'useradd example && echo "{{ .examplePublicKey }}" > /home/example/.ssh/authorized_keys'
    name: useradd-example.service
    roles:
    - Node
    - Master
  - manifest: |
      Type=oneshot
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/coreos-cloudinit --from-file=/home/core/cloud-config.yaml
    name: reboot-window.service
    roles:
    - Node
    - Master
  kubeAPIServer:
    authorizationRbacSuperUser: admin
    featureGates:
      TaintBasedEvictions: "true"
  kubeControllerManager:
    featureGates:
      TaintBasedEvictions: "true"
    horizontalPodAutoscalerUseRestClients: false
  kubeScheduler:
    featureGates:
      TaintBasedEvictions: "true"
  kubelet:
    featureGates:
      TaintBasedEvictions: "true"
  fileAssets:
  - content: |
      yes
    name: docker-1.12
    path: /etc/coreos/docker-1.12
    roles:
    - Node
    - Master
  - content: |
      #cloud-config
      coreos:
        update:
          reboot-strategy: "etcd-lock"
        locksmith:
          window-start: {{ .locksmith.windowStart }}
          window-length: {{ .locksmith.windowLength }}
    name: cloud-config.yaml
    path: /home/core/cloud-config.yaml
    roles:
    - Node
    - Master
  api:
    dns: {}
  authorization:
    rbac: {}
  channel: stable
  cloudProvider: aws
  configBase: s3://my-bucket.example.io/{{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
  etcdClusters:
  - etcdMembers:
    - instanceGroup: master-{{ .zone }}
      name: a
    name: main
  - etcdMembers:
    - instanceGroup: master-{{ .zone }}
      name: a
    name: events
  iam:
    allowContainerRegistry: true
    legacy: false
  kubernetesApiAccess:
  - {{ .apiAccessCidr }}
  kubernetesVersion: {{ .k8sVersion }}
  masterPublicName: api.{{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
  networkCIDR: {{ .vpcCidr }}
  networkID: {{ .vpcId }}
  networking:
    canal: {}
  nonMasqueradeCIDR: 100.64.0.0/10
  sshAccess:
  - {{ .sshAccessCidr }}
  subnets:
  - cidr: {{ $subnetCidr }}
    name: {{ .zone }}
    type: Public
    zone: {{ .zone }}
  topology:
    dns:
      type: Public
    masters: public
    nodes: public
---
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: {{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
  name: master-{{ .zone }}
spec:
{{- if .additionalSecurityGroups }}
  additionalSecurityGroups:
{{- range .additionalSecurityGroups }}
  - {{ . }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
  image: {{ .image }}
  machineType: {{ .awsMachineTypeMaster }}
  maxSize: 1
  minSize: 1
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: master-{{ .zone }}
  role: Master
  subnets:
  - {{ .zone }}
---
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: {{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
  name: nodes
spec:
{{- if .additionalSecurityGroups }}
  additionalSecurityGroups:
{{- range .additionalSecurityGroups }}
  - {{ . }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
  image: {{ .image }}
  machineType: {{ .awsMachineTypeNode }}
  maxSize: {{ .nodeCount }}
  minSize: {{ .nodeCount }}
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: nodes
  role: Node
  subnets:
  - {{ .zone }}
---
apiVersion: kops/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  name: ag.{{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: {{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
spec:
{{- if .additionalSecurityGroups }}
  additionalSecurityGroups:
{{- range .additionalSecurityGroups }}
  - {{ . }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
  image: {{ .image }}
  machineType: {{ .awsMachineTypeAg }}
  maxSize: 10
  minSize: 1
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: ag.{{ $clusterSubdomain }}.k8s.example.io
  role: Node
  subnets:
  - {{ .zone }}
```

And the values.yaml file:

```
# values.yaml:

region: us-west-2 
zone: us-west-2a  
environment: staging 
image: ami-abc123
awsMachineTypeNode: c5.large
awsMachineTypeMaster: m5.xlarge
awsMachineTypeAg: c5.large
nodeCount: "2"
k8sVersion: "1.9.3"
vpcId: vpc-abc123
vpcCidr: 172.23.0.0/16
apiAccessCidr: <e.g. office ip> 
sshAccessCidr: <e.g. office ip>
additionalSecurityGroups:
- sg-def234 # kubernetes-standard
- sg-abc123 # example scan engine targets
examplePublicKey: "ssh-rsa ..."
locksmith:
  windowStart: Mon 16:00 # 8am Monday PST
  windowLength: 4h
```

**2. Migrating the workloads on the cluster**

Not having any hands-on experience with Ark, [it does seem to fit your use case well](https://heptio.github.io/ark/v0.8.1/use-cases.html#cluster-migration):

> Cluster migration
>
> Using Backups and Restores
>
> Heptio Ark can help you port your resources from one cluster to
>   another, as long as you point each Ark Config to the same cloud object
>   storage. In this scenario, we are also assuming that your clusters are
>   hosted by the same cloud provider. Note that Heptio Ark does not
>   support the migration of persistent volumes across cloud providers.
>
> ```
> (Cluster 1) Assuming you haven’t already been checkpointing your data with the Ark schedule operation, you need to first back up your
> ```
>
> entire cluster (replacing  as desired):
>
> ```
> ark backup create <BACKUP-NAME>
>
> The default TTL is 30 days (720 hours); you can use the --ttl flag to change this as necessary.
>
> (Cluster 2) Make sure that the persistentVolumeProvider and backupStorageProvider fields in the Ark Config match the ones from
> ```
>
> Cluster 1, so that your new Ark server instance is pointing to the
>   same bucket.
>
> ```
> (Cluster 2) Make sure that the Ark Backup object has been created. Ark resources are synced with the backup files available in cloud
> ```
>
> storage.
>
> ```
> (Cluster 2) Once you have confirmed that the right Backup (<BACKUP-NAME>) is now present, you can restore everything with:
>
> ark restore create --from-backup <BACKUP-NAME>
> ```

Configuring Ark on AWS clusters seems straight-forward enough: https://github.com/heptio/ark/blob/master/docs/aws-config.md.

With some initial setup with the kops toolbox script and Ark configuration, you should have a clean, repeatable way to migrate your cluster and turn your pets into cattle, as the meme goes.

Comment: Sorry for the delay here. Went on vacation. This all seems good, but it doesn't seem like I am going to be able to easily reuse the same cluster name as well as the route53 records that exist for   the control plane and etcd cluster without extensive downtime. Ideally, I want an exact replica of the old kubernetes cluster with little downtime. This is seeming like an impossible task tbh